# Trouble while using "else"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't figure out what i am doing wrong.If someone uses the Wikipedia list,the if for wikipedia will be excecuted together with the else.

```
wikipedia=["search","infromation"]
weatherfor=["show weather","weather today","weather forecast","weather"]
action=(input("What would you want me to do : "))
if any(word in action for word in wikipedia):
  print("Here Is What I Found On Wikipedia.")
if any(word in action for word in weatherfor):
  print("The Weather For Today Is")
else:
  print ("Sorry I Haven't learnt this yet")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overkilled the `if` `else`, try this simple structure:

```
wikipedia=["search", "infromation"]
weatherfor=["show weather", "weather today", "weather forecast", "weather"]

action=(input("What would you want me to do : "))

if action in wikipedia:
  print("Here Is What I Found On Wikipedia.")
elif aaction in weatherfor:
  print("The Weather For Today Is")
else:
  print ("Sorry I Haven't learnt this yet")
```

The `in` would do the job of searching a given value in any iterable (`list` in this case)